# Updating div page coordinates in the datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jquery-ui, datastore

I'm currently making a webapp in App Engine where users can create multiple "boxes" (divs) with text inside of them.  These "boxes" can be dragged around the page.  I implemented the drag and drop functionality using the JQuery UI Draggable plugin.  I can easily display the current coordinate of each box on mouseup using:

```
$(this).offset();
```

Each box has an entity in the datastore which contains it's respective content. I was planning on just creating another member for the box entity which contains it's coordinates. This way, every time the user logs in to his account on the webapp, the boxes will appear where they were last. My problem is, I'm not sure how to update the datastore each time a box is dragged about the page. To be honest, I'm not sure if I'm even approaching the problem correctly. I would appreciate any guidance on how I can achieve this.

This is how the page is being rendered, just to give further insight:

```
 {% for box in boxes %}
 <div draggable="true" id="box" class="ui-widget-content draggable">
    <div id="title">
 {% if box.title %}
     {{ box.title }}<br>
 {% else %}
     Untitled<br>
 {% endif %}
 </div>
 <div id="content">
    {{ box.content }}<br>
 </div>
 <div id="menu">
    <a href="/edit/{{ box.key.id }}">View/Edit</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="/delete/{{ box.key.id }}">Delete</a>
 </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use JQuery to capture the 'drop' event, and fire off an AJAX request to your app, POSTing the ID of the box and the new coordinates, so it can update them in the datastore.